# ¿ Como insertar un elemento html en javascript con su 'id' variable dentro de un fichero .aspx?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Necesito insertar un elemento HTML desde JavaScript y que la id de ese elemento sea una variable.

Por ejemplo:

```
document.getElementById(miElemento1).innerHTML = '<select id="miElemento2" type="hidden" />';
```

substituido por esto pero

```
var idEle = "miElemento2";

document.getElementById(miElemento1).innerHTML = '<select id=idEle type="hidden" />';
```

donde idEle seria la variable.. pero no funciona.

Otro ejemplo:

```
 var idCF = "tFIP";
 var idCFd = idCF + "d";
 var idCFm = idCF + "m";
 var idCFa = idCF + "a";
 var idCFdd = idCF + "dd";
 var idCFmm = idCF + "mm";
 var idCFaa = idCF + "aa";
 var idCFdma = idCFd + idCFm + idCFa;

 document.getElementById(idCF).innerHTML =
          "<select id='" + idCFd + "' name='" + idCFd + "' class='form-control' runat='server' style='width:60px; margin-right: 5px;' required ></select>" +
          "<select id='" + idCFm + "' name='" + idCFm + "' class='form-control' runat='server' style='width:60px; margin-right: 5px;' required ></select>" +
          "<select id='" + idCFa + "' name='" + idCFa + "' class='form-control' runat='server' style='width:65px;' required ></select>" +
          "<input  id='" + idCFdma + "' type='hidden' value='' runat='server' />" +
          "<input  id='" + idCFdd + "'  type='hidden' value='' runat='server' />" +
          "<input  id='" + idCFmm + "'  type='hidden' value='' runat='server' />" +
          "<input  id='" + idCFaa + "'  type='hidden' value='' runat='server' />";
```

Pero no funciona ya que me sale el siguiente error:

```
'" + idCFa + "' no es un identificador válido.      
'" + idCFaa + "' no es un identificador válido. 
'" + idCFd + "' no es un identificador válido.  
'" + idCFdd + "' no es un identificador válido.     
'" + idCFdma + "' no es un identificador válido.        
'" + idCFm + "' no es un identificador válido.      
'" + idCFmm + "' no es un identificador válido.
```

Haciendo mas pruebas parece que el error me viene porque quiero usar ese elemento con runat='server' también en el servidor de .aspx por lo que parece que es difícil cambiar el valor de la variable id en tiempo de ejecución

Comment: No puedes insertar una variable como elemento html, puedes insertar el valor de la varible mas no la variable como tal.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar la propiedad `.id`

```js
let idB = 'idB';
let idC = idB + 'C';
let idD = idC + 'D';

console.log(document.getElementById('a'));
document.getElementById('a').id=idB;
console.log(document.getElementById(idB));
document.getElementById(idB).id=idC;
console.log(document.getElementById(idC));
document.getElementById(idC).id=idD;
console.log(document.getElementById(idD))
```

```html
<input type='text' id="a">
```

EDIT: Si lo que queres hacer es agregar un nuevo elemento seria algo asi

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let container = document.getElementById('container');
  let select = document.createElement('select');
  
  select.id = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  container.appendChild(select);
  console.log(select);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <select id='1'></select>
</div>
<br>
<button id="btn">Crear nuevo select con id distinto</button>
```

Comment: no entiendo el código que has puesto. Necesito insertar un código HTML con sus ids que sean variables. Voy  a poner otro ejemplo.

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es cambiar el id del input type text
Vos queres cambiar el id del select? o crear uno nuevo con un id variable?

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es cambiar el nombre de la variable del id mediante una variable. El proyecto es HTML dentro de un fichero .aspx

Comment: Creo que acabo de encontrar el error tiene que ver con usar ese elemento con runat='server" para el lado del servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Para el caso del primer ejemplo no te funciona porque la variable debe estar afuera del contenido, en este caso seria así:

```
var idEle = "miElemento2";
document.getElementById("miElemento1").innerHTML = '<select id="'+idEle+'" type="hidden" />';
```

En el caso del segundo ejemplo, no me aparece ningún error, tal cual copie lo que pusiste, y me funciono a la perfección.

jsfiddle: [Primer Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/4hytqwgv/)

jsfiddle: [Segundo Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/L123kwa4/)

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tomar el tiempo en responder. Es mejor tratar de colocar el código directamente acá; que colocar solo los enlaces. Ademas en SOes el editor de texto tiene una funcionalidad para colocar código (HTML, CSS y JS) que se pueda "correr" para ver el ejemplo funcionando.

Comment: @CesarRomero Ya lo sé, pero el OP comentó en otra respuesta que no entendía el código puesto. Esa es la desventaja del sistema de SO, en cambio con el jsfiddle el OP tiene en su visual al mismo tiempo todo el código estructurado así como el resultado. En cuanto a que solo coloque los enlaces, no se si leíste completa la respuesta que le dí al OP: en el caso del primer ejemplo que el puso, si fue necesario colocar el código corregido. EN el caso de la segunda, no, ya que el código que él puso funciona correctamente, y el volverlo a poner sería spamear el hilo. Saludos

Comment: Hola, pues en Visual Studio 2017 no me llega a compilar el segundo ejemplo. Se debe hacer un lio el compilador !! Me muestra el dichoso mensaje de 'no es un identificador valido' el fichero es un .aspx

Comment: Creo que acabo de encontrar el error tiene que ver con usar ese elemento con runat='server" para el lado del servidor pensaba que no influiría.

Comment: El problema entonces es del servidor .aspx que no me reconoce la id con runat='server'

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza template strings:

OJO, solo puedes insertar texto y números en el contenido HTML, los template strings se crean usando estas comillas especiales: ``, en mi teclado se hacen con las teclas alt gr + la tecla con la que haces este simbolo: }.

La forma de usarlos es la siguiente:

```js
let variableTemplate = 5;
let elemento = document.getElementById("elemento");
elemento.innerHTML =  `${variableTemplate}`;
```

```html
<div id = "elemento"></div>
```

```
/*Notese como la variable a usar se introdujo en medio de estos simbolos "${}",
Dentro de estas llaves junto con el símbolo de dolar "Extraes", el contenido
de la variable y lo juntas como un string*/
```

También existe otra opción la cual es mas compatible con navegadores mas antiguos o el renegado de internet explorer y es sin usar template strings, consiste en usar el operador +, para concatenar lo que necesitas:

```js
let id = "miId";
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1 style = 'color: blue'" + "id = '" + id + "'>" + id + '</h1>';
```

En este caso cuando necesitamos que aparezcan comillas en nuestros atributos en el elemento html, lo que podemos hacer es, agregarlas dentro de unas comillas dobles, y las comillas que harán parte de los atributos html, las agregamos como simples, de no ser así y agregas comillas dobles o simples tanto como en los atributos que harán parte del elemento como al literal de la cadena de texto, entonces por obligación tendrás que usar el comando de escape de caracteres para las comillas que harán parte del html:

```js
let id = "miId";
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1 style = \"color: blue\"" + "id = \"" + id + "\">" + id + "</h1>";
```

En tu caso, si es que no entendí mal, lo que necesitas es que tu id del elemento que necesitas cambie a ser el valor de una variable cierto??, mostrar un id con el contenido de una variable es totalmente valido, y mas de la forma en la que la estabas haciendo, sin embargo, aquí te dejare el ejemplo de como se puede hacer lo que tu necesitas usando los template strings de ES6, (Tal vez hallas hecho un error de tipado en tu código original y se te halla escapado alguna comilla), ya que en mi caso el código que pusiste donde hay muchas variables de ids me funciono a la perfección, sin mas, aquí los template strings:

```js
let idCF = "tFIP";
let idCFd = idCF + "d";
let idCFm = idCF + "m";
let idCFa = idCF + "a";
       
document.getElementById(idCF).innerHTML =

`<select id = '${idCFd}' name = '${idCFd}' class = 'form-control' runat = 'server' style = 'width: 60px; margin-right: 5px;' required></select>` +
`<select id = '${idCFm}' name = '${idCFm}' class = 'form-control' runat = 'server' style = 'width: 60px; margin-right: 5px;' required></select>` +
`<select id = '${idCFa}' name = '${idCFa}' class = 'form-control' runat = 'server' style = 'width: 65px;' required></select>`
```

```html
<div id="tFIP"></div>
```

**Nota:** El código de arriba fue hecho como una prueba de como usar los template strings, para que practiques con ellos pensé en no escribir todas las variables y el contenido original que me diste si no que mas bien tu apartir de el ejemplo incrustado aquí puedas lograr implementar este código con los demás elementos y variables que tienes en el ejemplo original.

**Nota importante:** No le prestes atención a la palabra reservada let, esta simplemente es otra forma de definir las variables, aunque en este caso en un ámbito de bloque, sin embargo, esto no interesa a la hora de almacenar variables usando template strings, es decir, puedes usar cómodamente var, let o const según lo que necesites y el resultado será el mismo. sin embargo como experiencia personal, usa const siempre que vayas a almacenar un valor que nunca vaya a cambiar, de resto deberías utilizar siempre let, porque var ya no la recomiendo, prácticamente esta obsoleta y es poco practica y avecez hasta conflictiva.

**NOTA IMPORTANTE 2:** Los templates strings, cuando concatenas o no una variable de la manera ${}, no nececitas salirte de estas para poder seguir escribiendo lo demás que necesites, es decir, supongamos que tienes lo siguiente:

```
const nombre = "luis";
const edad = 18
console.log(`Hola mi nombre es ${luis} y tengo ${edad} años`);

//Imprimira en consola:  `Mi nombre es ${luis} y tengo ${edad} años`
```

***Dato curioso 1:*** Los template strings, respetan tanto los espacios como los saltos de linea. Si añades espacios y saltos de linea a una cadena de template string, estos se verán reflejados en el texto o cadena.

***Dato curioso 2:*** Como los template strings extraen "valores", ¡esto significa que podemos ejecutar funciones que retornen determinados valores para concatenar este resultado a la cadena de texto! ejemplo:

```js
function getRandNumb(limit){

   let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * limit);
   return rand;

}

document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>¡El numero aleatorio es: ${getRandNumb(10)}!<h1>`;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda pero he probado también con template strings y me tira el mismo error. No se si es por alguna particularidad de Visual Studio 2017. El fichero donde tengo el HTML es un .aspx

Comment: Creo que acabo de encontrar el error tiene que ver con usar ese elemento con runat='server" para el lado del servidor pensaba que no influiría.

Comment: Por lo tanto necesitaría una solución que fuera valida para que el servidor en aspx.net me reconociera esa id